coordinates of the vector relative to the new basis
Given vectors $(v, b_1, b_2, b_3,...,b_n)$ defined by their coordinates in an arbitrary basis. Prove that the vectors $(b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots, b_n)$ form a basis and find the coordinates of the vector $(v)$ relative to the new basis:
$$ b_1(2,1,3), b_2(3,2,-5), b_3(1,-1,1), v(6,2,-7)$$
I will divide my answer into 2 parts. Part 1 - proving their basis by checking the determinant of the given vectors $$b_1,b_2,b_3 = 1 \neq 0$$ meaning it's a basis. Part 2 - Assuming the new basis is $C$, I'm trying to understand which calculation I need to perform, is it :
$$ A(E \rightarrow B)= \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & -1 \\
3 & -5 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$ is a matrix from the standard basis to basis B noted by $E \rightarrow B $ multiplied by some vector $x,y,z$ equal to $[v]_c$?
If so, in which basis this vector $x,y,z$
I also wrote the answer but I want to understand the logic behind it

By definition, $A\cdot x$ is the linear combination of the columns of $A$ with the coefficients $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. If the columns of $A$ are a basis in which you want to represent $v$ you thus have to solve $A\cdot x=v$ (which, btw, one should not do by calculating the inverse of $A$).

The answer should be $$  \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & -1 \\
3 & -5 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z   
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
6 \\ 2 \\ -7   
\end{bmatrix} $$
We calculate $A^{-1}$ and multiply it to the left of $\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\ 2 \\ -7   
\end{bmatrix} $ in this way:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z   
\end{bmatrix} = A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
6 \\ 2 \\ -7   
\end{bmatrix} $$ which is $(1,1,1)$
